# Can't set OBJECTS_DIR from .pri file

Tags: qmake

I want to have one directory for all object files and create Common.pri file that set OBJECTS_DIR like that

```
OBJECTS_DIR = $$PWD/../
```

But when build project i can't find obj file in given directory.If I write this direct in .pro file I get the expected result.I successfully include Common.pri file. I checked that with

```
!include( ../../Common.pri)::warning(Fail to include Common.pri)
```

How to achieve what i want.I can't find anything in google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PWD](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pwd) variable specifies the full path leading to the directory containing the current file being parsed, that is, in your case the full path leading to the Common.pri file and NOT the .pro file. I would place a `warning($$OBJECTS_DIR)` function in both the .pri and the .pro file to verify the value of OBJECTS_DIR variable.

Comment: Thanks this is useful but not answear the question how to get relative path to .pro file

Comment: @themean What you need is the [_PRO_FILE_PWD_](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#pro-file-pwd) variable, which contains the path to the directory containing the project file in use.